# jquery ajax does not work in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm in the middle of an asp.net webform project. I want to use jquery ajax.
here is my code:

```
     <asp:Button ID="btn_comment" runat="server" CssClass="contact_btn pull-right" Text="send" OnClientClick="callajax(event)" />
```

ajax function :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function callajax(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../Music.aspx/sendcomment",
            data: '{name: "' + $("#<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>").text() + '" , email:"' + $("#<%=TextBox2.ClientID%>").text() + '" , website: "' + $("#<%=TextBox4.ClientID%>").text() + '" , comment: "' + $("#<%=TextBox3.ClientID%>").text() + '" }',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                if (response.d) {
                    alert('ok');
                }

            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert('eror');
            }
        });
        }
</script>
```

sendcomment method :

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static void sendcomment(string name , string email , string website , string comment)
        {
          // do something
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }
```

I also add jquery file to my project but when I run the project and click on button it does not work and fire the sendcomment method.
I also use updatepanel but it doesn't work.Can anyone help me?

Comment: Try with onclick instead onclientclick.. any console errors?

Comment: do you get an alert for error ?

Comment: Where is `event` defined?  Check the JavaScript console for errors.  When you step through in the browser's debugger, where/how specifically does it fail?

Comment: Also note that your server-side code (1) doesn't compile and (2) ignores exceptions.

Comment: the server-side code does not fire :-(

Comment: Did you create your web method on the same page's code side?

Comment: yes...
I check the console for erors : 
http://localhost:21276/Music.aspx/sendcomment Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: I don't get alert for error.

Comment: Also change `OnClientClick="..."` to `OnClientClick="return callajax(event)"`  and `return false;` from the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this as url

```
url: "Music.aspx/sendcomment",
```

Comment: I use this but it does not fix.

Comment: debug your code and stop it on the if (response.d) { line check what is the message

Comment: I remove the / from /Music.aspx/sendcomment and it's worked. thanks
It was very sily problem...